# How can I make this query run faster?

Tags: mysql

I'm just wondering if theres anything I could do to make the query run a bit faster?

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE posts.exists = 'n'
ORDER BY posts.ratecount DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

*Takes: 2.47s @ 0,100 | 6.18s @ 500,100*

This works but it tends to get rather slow as the limit increases (100,100 > 200,100 etc).

Using an index doesn't seem to help either:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
USE INDEX(ratecount_ca)
WHERE posts.exists = 'n'
ORDER BY posts.ratecount DESC
LIMIT 0,100
```

*Takes: 8.59s @ 0,100 | 28.98s @ 500,100*

Strangely enough, without the WHERE it works perfect.

A descending index would most likely fix the issue but since that doesn't seem to be implemented yet, I need another option.
Doing the WHERE after it's ordered would mostly likely speed it up too, but since I'm rather new to SQL I have no idea how to do :<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you using? v5.0 docs suggest there is a way to change index order.

I would suggest to create index on both columns. It should look something like:

```
CREATE INDEX index_2_cols ON posts(exists, ratecount DESC);
```

Comment: Can you post how much performance improved? Just for my curiosity :)

Comment: Went from 8.59s > 0.93s. Fairly sure it could go lower, but this works for what I need it for. :3
Fairly sure it's because you actually can't change the index order yet even though the option is there:
"An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order"

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that omitting the where condition makes it run fast, I would try to [create an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on `exists` field of the `posts` table:

```
CREATE INDEX ON posts_exists ON posts (exists(10));
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work, it was still about the same speed as the second query.